# Turtlebot bringup problems

Tags: ros, turtlebot, groovy-turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having problems with the turtlebot_bringup package on Turtlebo 1 (iRobot Create base).

I am using ROS Groovy on both the netbook and workstation, and I have edited the minimal.launch file such that TURTLEBOT_BASE=create, TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles and TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect. I have made sure that the udev/rules.d had the correct specification and the launch files were indeed pointing to ttyUSB0. But when I turn the turtlebot on and run minimal.launch, the turtlebot turns off automatically, and the launch file keeps popping up errors such as "No data from sci", "Please ensure Create is powered on and plugged in" etc. The dashboard on the workstation reports that everything is "stale".

Any advice on how to proceed would be very helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58588/turtlebot-bringup-problems/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This usually happens when the battery is very low or going bad. I would get a multimeter and see what the battery voltage is, if it's close to 12V the battery is going bad.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0